# Android Application Memory Usage Analysis Tools

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

my developing an Android application that currently uses about 32mb of RAM when running. I wanted to lower this usage. Are there any tool available that will allow me to see what parts of my application (Activity, Service, etc) are eating up memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a simple Google search for Android memory analysis will turn up a lot of relevant information. The first item of which for me was this [Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) which has a lot of useful stuff including information on the HPROF tool.